# ASP.NET MVC coding with SQL Server database with composite keys & update cascade feature

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, many-to-many, ef-database-first, soft-delete

I am using EF 6 with a database-first approach for my ASP.NET MVC project as I am more comfortable with SQL than C# & LINQ coding (using SQL Server 2008, Visual Studio 2015).

I have 4 tables in SQL Server each for :

```
Link, Employee, MapLinkEmp, Location 

viz, link_sd1, emp_sd1, MapEmpLink_sd1, loc_sd1 respectively
```

A `Link` has many-to-many relations with `Emp` table for which I created another table referencing the composite primary keys of both the tables.

In order to implement soft deletes, I researched and ultimately followed the approach mentioned in
 [Entity framework override save changes to soft delete entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678359/entity-framework-override-save-changes-to-soft-delete-entities?rq=1), which suggests composite keys for which I referred to 
 [how to map composite key in CRUD functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138022/how-to-map-composite-key-in-crud-functionality)

At database end of my project: 
I implemented cascading feature using composite keys in SQL Server
But at Application end :
I am unable to incorporate CRUD + other features (including soft delete, location-wise grouping of Emp & Link data, `Emp` with their respective location can update only their emp data and link data  etc) when there are composite keys in my entities.

[image: Database Diagram below:]

SQL Server code for cascading :

```
ALTER TABLE emplinkloc_sd1
ADD emid int

ALTER TABLE emplinkloc_sd1
ADD lmid int

ALTER TABLE emplinkloc_sd1
ADD isdl bit DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE emplinkloc_sd1
ADD isde bit DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE emplinkloc_sd1
ADD PRIMARY KEY (melid)

ALTER TABLE emplinkloc_sd1
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ell_e_sd1 
    FOREIGN KEY (emid, isde) REFERENCES emp_sd1(eid, isdeleted) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE emplinkloc_sd1
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ell_l_sd1 
    FOREIGN KEY (lmid, isdl) REFERENCES link_sd1(lid, isdeleted) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I found many techniques like `ISoftDelete`, `Interceptor` etc, but I think such concepts are used in either code-first approaches or EF Core etc. Also these require a lot of programming that exceeds my current level of understanding.

I have done most in the Database end (as suggested in [Entity framework override save changes to soft delete entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678359/entity-framework-override-save-changes-to-soft-delete-entities?rq=1)), 
how should I incorporate the features on the application side  in the controller & views of ASP.NET MVC with such a database schema(having composite primary & foreign keys) using EF database-first approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am explaining the technique - **"Database First Approach with CRUD Operation Using Stored Procedure with EF6"** that worked best for me after lot of experimentation. The whole process includes steps at Database end and then at Application End, as described below for an entity - Employee (emp_Oct1 in my case, with *eid* & *isdeletede* as its Composite Keys):

**DATABASE END**

**Step 1.**  I designed Schema as below (with composite keys):
[image: Database Schema]

**Step 2.**  I created Stored Procedures in SQL Server for Create,Update & Soft Deletion for my entity "emp_Oct1" as shown below:

```
 ---- For SOFT DELETION -----
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_deleteempt1_Oc1]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @eid int
    AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE emp_Oct1 SET isdeletede='1' WHERE eid=@eid 
END

----- For CREATE & UPDATE -----
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_AddEditEmp_Oct1
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @eid int=0, --Named Parameter setting initial value with the parameter
    @name varchar(100),
    @cpf varchar(50),
    @Designation varchar(50),
    @Contact bigint,
    @email varchar(255),
    @emplocid int,
    @Pwd varchar(100),
    @Remarks varchar(200),
    @isdeletede bit,
    @elast_mod_dt datetime2,
    @elast_mod_by varchar(255) 
    AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    IF(@eid>0)
        BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        UPDATE emp_Oct1 SET 
        name=@name,cpf=@cpf,Designation=@Designation,Contact=@Contact,email=@email, emplocid=@emplocid,
        Pwd=@Pwd ,Remarks=@Remarks,isdeletede=@isdeletede,elast_mod_dt=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,elast_mod_by=@elast_mod_by
        WHERE eid=@eid 
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO emp_Oct1(name,cpf,Designation,Contact,email,emplocid,Pwd,Remarks,isdeletede,elast_mod_dt,elast_mod_by) 
        VALUES(@name,@cpf,@Designation,@Contact,@email,@emplocid,@Pwd,@Remarks,@isdeletede,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@elast_mod_by)
        SELECT @eid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        END
    SELECT @eid as eid
END
GO
```

**APPLICATION END**

**Step 1.** Create MVC Application, Add Entity Data Model, as described [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/create-entity-data-model.aspx)

**Step 2.**  I implemented my CRUD through Stored Procedures with the main idea from this source[CRUD Operations using Stored Procedure in Entity Framework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/CRUD-using-stored-procedures.aspx).

**Step 3.** Controller Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using llpv5;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;

namespace llpv5.Controllers
{
    public class emp_Oct1Controller : Controller
    {
       
        private MyEntity db = new MyEntity();

       
        // Emp with their respective location can see only the data  of their location
        public ActionResult resplocemp_linq()
        {
            
            var usercpf = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            var userlocid = (from e in db.emp_Oct1 where e.cpf == usercpf select e.emplocid).FirstOrDefault(); //To find location ID of the logged in user
            var linkresult = (from l in db.emp_Oct1
                              join loc in db.loc_Oct1
                              on l.emplocid equals loc.locid
                              where l.emplocid == userlocid
                              && l.isdeletede == false
                              && l.name != "Admin"
                              select l).ToList();

            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                linkresult = (from l in db.emp_Oct1
                              join loc in db.loc_Oct1
                              on l.emplocid equals loc.locid
                              where l.emplocid == userlocid
                              && l.isdeletede == false
                              && l.name != "Admin"
                              select l).ToList();
            }
            return View(linkresult.ToList());
        }
        //For Admin only - Deleted items
        
        // GET: emp_sd1
        public ActionResult isdeindex()
        {
            var emp_sd1 = db.emp_Oct1.Include(e => e.loc_Oct1).Where(e => e.isdeletede).Where(e => e.name != "Admin");
            return View(emp_sd1.ToList());
        }
        
        // GET: emp_Oct1
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var emp_Oct1 = db.emp_Oct1.Include(e => e.loc_Oct1).Where(e => !e.isdeletede).Where(e => e.name != "Admin");
            return View(emp_Oct1.ToList());
        }
       
        // GET: emp_Oct1/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? eid, bool isdeletede)
        {
            if (eid == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            emp_Oct1 emp_Oct1 = db.emp_Oct1.Find(eid, isdeletede);
            if (emp_Oct1 == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(emp_Oct1);
        }
       
        // GET: emp_Oct1/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.emplocid = new SelectList(db.loc_Oct1, "locid", "LocationName");
            return View();
        }
        
        // POST: emp_Oct1/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "eid,name,cpf,Designation,Contact,email,emplocid,Pwd,Remarks,isdeletede,elast_mod_dt,elast_mod_by")] emp_Oct1 emp_Oct1)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                emp_Oct1.elast_mod_by = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                db.emp_Oct1.Add(emp_Oct1);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("gindex_filter1");
            }

            ViewBag.emplocid = new SelectList(db.loc_Oct1, "locid", "LocationName", emp_Oct1.emplocid);
            return View(emp_Oct1);
        }
       
        // GET: emp_Oct1/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? eid, bool isdeletede)
        {
            if (eid == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            emp_Oct1 emp_Oct1 = db.emp_Oct1.Find(eid, isdeletede);
            if (emp_Oct1 == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.emplocid = new SelectList(db.loc_Oct1, "locid", "LocationName", emp_Oct1.emplocid);
            return View(emp_Oct1);
        }
       
        // POST: emp_Oct1/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "eid,name,cpf,Designation,Contact,email,emplocid,Pwd,Remarks,isdeletede,elast_mod_dt,elast_mod_by")] emp_Oct1 emp_Oct1)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                emp_Oct1.elast_mod_by = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                db.Entry(emp_Oct1).State = EntityState.Modified;
              
                return RedirectToAction("gindex_filter1");
            }
            ViewBag.emplocid = new SelectList(db.loc_Oct1, "locid", "LocationName", emp_Oct1.emplocid);
            return View(emp_Oct1);
        }
       
        // GET: emp_Oct1/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? eid, bool isdeletede)
        {
            if (eid == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            emp_Oct1 emp_Oct1 = db.emp_Oct1.Find(eid, isdeletede);
            if (emp_Oct1 == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(emp_Oct1);
        }
        
        // POST: emp_Oct1/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int eid, bool isdeletede)
        {
            emp_Oct1 emp_Oct1 = db.emp_Oct1.Find(eid, isdeletede);
            db.emp_Oct1.Remove(emp_Oct1);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("gindex_filter1");
        }


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4.** Make appropriate changes in the auto-generated Views, using  [this link: how to map composite key in CRUD functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138022/how-to-map-composite-key-in-crud-functionality)
Sample View Code as follows:

```
@model IEnumerable<llpv5.emp_Oct1>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Location-specific Users";
}

<center><h2>Location-specific Users</h2></center>


<table class="table table-hover  table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr class="table-primary">
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cpf)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>

            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Designation)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact)
        </th>
        <th>
               @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pwd)   
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.loc_Oct1.LocationName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cpf)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Designation)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                { @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pwd)   }
            </td>


            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.loc_Oct1.LocationName)
            </td>


            <td>

                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { eid = item.eid, isdeletede = item.isdeletede }) <text> | </text>
              
               @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { eid = item.eid, isdeletede = item.isdeletede }) <text> | </text>
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { eid = item.eid, isdeletede = item.isdeletede })
              
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```